# Max Character in JSON Parsing

Tags: php, android, json, char, max

What is the max char in json parsing, and how to display large text like 800 char?

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "desc": null
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "desc": null
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "desc": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I have problem when my database has 900 char the "JSON" showed null.

Comment: Developed a project that is having the same problem, long texts cause a break in ajax and still not know how to solve, I'll watch this post

Comment: Can you find the data size of transferring data by bytes. The default post size of Apache Tomcat is 2MB but if you wan't to send a data above 2MB then you must specify the **maxPostSize** in server.xml file of tomcat. Have a look at this link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Comment: @Ajeesh this also applies to apache?

Comment: i think its not about data size, the problem is charachter limit like 90 chars each parsing

Comment: If it's **Apache Tomcat** server then it's post size is 2MB by default. But I am sure about other servers. I added this comment because this may also cause these problems.